# Comapre List of entity with list of data from frontend and update field which are matching in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to deduct the available quantity  with the matching itemcode  of the stock

json data from postman

```
 [billamount:1000,
disocunt:500,
billcart[{itemcode:1001, quantity:4 }, {itemcode:1002, quantity:7 }]]
```

method

```
 @Autowired
private StockRepository stockRepository;

public Bill createBill(Bill bill) {

 for (Billcart data : bill.getBillcart()) {
  Stock entity = stockRepository.findByItemcode(data.getItemcode());

 if(entity.getItemcode() ==data.getItemcode()){
   entity.setAvailableQuantity(entity.getAvailableQuantity()- data.getQuantity())
stockRepository.save(entity)
  }
}
```

before deduction

```
 [{itemcode:1001, availableQuantity:20 }, {itemcode:1002, availableQuantity:40 }]]
```

result should be like this:

```
 [{itemcode:1001, availableQuantity:16 }, {itemcode:1002, availableQuantity:33 }]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to also update the values your bill:

```
@Autowired
private StockRepository stockRepository;

@Transactional
public Bill createBill(Bill bill) {
  for (Billcart data : bill.getBillcart()) {
    Stock entity = stockRepository.findByItemcode(data.getItemcode());
    entity.setAvailableQuantity(
      entity.getAvailableQuantity()-data.getQuantity());
    entity = stockRepository.save(entity);
    data.setAvailableQuantity(entity.getAvailableQuantity());
  }
}
```